# Compression of Objects

Tags: .net, reactjs, http, asp.net-core

We need to return file attachments from WebAPI on ASP.net Core 5 to frontend on react. We need to make sure objects exchanged are fully compressed and then decompressed on frontend to save network traffic.

Can we rely on normal ASP.net dynamic content compression (if one is there) or need to do that explicitly on both frontend and backend using corresponding code?

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: so far found that there is Asp.net Response Compression. But still finding, if i can use it for only specific responses where i have documents as attachments. This is because i don't want to compress all responses

Comment: Have you checked this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: yes checking that already if it allow me to take specific items only to compress